# Can't create directory

Tags: magento2.2, permissions, file-permissions

```
[2018-01-12 11:58:16] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /home/hortbrascom/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/. in [Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor] {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Can't create directory /home/hortbrascom/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/. in [Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor] at /home/hortbrascom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115)"} []
```

Im using Magento 2.2.2 | CentOS 7.4 | WHM 68.0.23

I know its an know issue about permissions, but i gave right permissions yesterday, and today the error returned.

Now i got this:

```
{"0":"Class Magento\\Authorization\\Model\\Acl\\Role\\GroupFactory does not exist","1":"#0 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Definition\/Runtime.php(44): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\\\Authori...')\n#1 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\\\Authori...')\n#2 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\\\Authori...')\n#3 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\\\Authori...')\n#4 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\\\Framewo...', NULL, 'roleLoader', 'Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#5 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(34): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#6 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(59): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#7 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#8 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Acl\/Builder\/Proxy.php(84): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#9 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Acl\/Builder\/Proxy.php(95): Magento\\Framework\\Acl\\Builder\\Proxy->_getSubject()\n#10 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session.php(227): Magento\\Framework\\Acl\\Builder\\Proxy->getAcl()\n#11 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session\/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session->processLogin()\n#12 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/Auth.php(159): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->processLogin()\n#13 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth->login('admin', 'admin123')\n#14 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->___callParent('login', Array)\n#15 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('admin', 'admin123')\n#16 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)\n#17 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(205): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->login('admin', 'admin123')\n#18 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(157): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#19 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(125): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#20 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#21 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#22 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#23 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#24 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#25 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#26 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#27 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#28 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#29 \/home\/site\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#30 \/home\/site\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#31 \/home\/site\/public_html\/index.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#32 {main}","url":"\/admin\/admin\/index\/index\/key\/a1049503f810d2386018104cb6e8418c7b239c7958782fb8fcb611da24b01b53\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Comment: did u setted cron?

Comment: Yes i did. I deleted generated and the folder keeps popping up even deleting it and its files ...

Answer (score 3):

### **main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory**

> This is a permission problem, Magento is unable to write to your generated directory.
>
> Please [check this documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) to setup your permissions properly.
>
> If you have SSH details then run following command from your magento root directory
>
> **sudo chmod -R 777 pub/media pub/static var generated**

### **Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\GroupFactory does not exist**

> try following solution
>
> 1. root> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> 2. root> sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/generation/* pub/static/*
> 3. Give write permisson for pub/media pub/static var generated
>
> **sudo chmod -R 777 pub/media pub/static var generated**

Comment: By magento documentation 777 inst recommend, but if i set 755 doens't work... you know why?

Comment: 755 means you can access and read the files only you can not write files in any folder with this permission and magento 2 generates files in these folders (pub/media, pub/static, var, generated) during loading page or execution of any command (upgrade, deploy, etc....) so you have to set 777.

Answer (score 0):

If you have  created cron using

```
crontab -e
```

Then remove cron from their and add cron using below command

```
crontab -e -u www-data
```

Comment: Second command doens't work, i'm using cpanel.

Comment: Yes i did. I deleted generated and the folder keeps popping up even deleting it and our files ...